# How to format a date in moment js

Tags: momentjs

How to format 2019-07-29T05:55:00 to 29 Jul 2019 (Mon) in moment js ? What should be the formatdate string ? 'DD MMM YYYY (ddd)  is not accepted by moment js

Answer (score 1):

I'm not allowed to comment yet, but I when I saw your question I was sure your format was correct.

`var now = moment().format('DD MMM YYYY (ddd)');`

Tried it out in JS fiddle and it works.

Answer (score 0):

It should be working fine, the correct syntax:
var test = moment().format('DD MMM YYYY (ddd)');

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myDate = moment('2019-07-29T05:55:00').format('DD MMM YYYY (ddd)');
result.innerHTML = myDate ;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.js"></script>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```